# python shape mismatch error when using bar

Tags: python

so actually today i started learning matplob and now I have a shape mismatch error and cant find the way to fix that.

my code :

```
num = [4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 8, 1, 1, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0]
key = ["less1(A)", "less1(B)", "less1(C)", "less1(D)", "less2(A)", "less2(B)", "less2(C)", 
"less2(D)",
"less3(A)", "less3(B)", "less3(C)", "less3(D)", "less4(A)", "less4(B)", "less4(C)", 
"less4(D)",
"less5(A)", "less5(B)", "less5(C)", "less5(D)"]

 x = np.array(key)
 y = np.array(nomarat)
 plt.bar(x, y, width=0.1)
 plt.show()
```

error :

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is 
between arg 0 with shape (20,) and arg 1 with shape (5,).
```

thanks

Comment: Your x and y are not the same length. What is `nomarat`?

Comment: they are the same length . some numbers in int type

Comment: The error clearly says they are not the same length.

Comment: yeah i found that too but there i dont know why

Comment: Please correct your code with the definition of `nomarat`. As is it's impossible to know what your `y` variable contains.

Answer (score 1):

The two arrays you are trying to plot with the bar() function have different lengths. The x array (key) has 20 elements while the y array (num) has 5 elements. The bar() function requires that the two arrays have the same length.

Comment: hi, i got len of each list and both was 20

Comment: @Aminshahrabi make sure to get length of `x` and `y`, not `key` and `num`, since you use `nomarat`, not `num`.

Comment: oh, thanks a bad mistake